# Jenkins Polling Ignore Ignores All Builds

Tags: git, jenkins, polling

I am trying to set up a Jenkins job that builds automatically when the repo is updated, however I would like to ignore modifications made by other Jenkins jobs modifying the repository.

The two ways I can think to do this would be to exclude specific messages or to exclude specific committers. I'm aware that this can be updated by going to the Job config page --> Source Code Management --> Git --> Add --> Polling ignores commits from certain users/with certain messages.

My issue is that as soon as I enable this polling ignore, all modifications to my repository are ignored.

To ignore specific committers I have tried leaving the field blank as well as listing a user that I do not use to make commits. To ignore commits with certain messages I have tried using the following message: 
`.*\[maven-release-plugin\].*`
as well as no message, however as soon as either of the polling ignores are added to the job ALL polling is ignored and no jobs are triggered, regardless of the commit message or user.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a workaround?

Jenkins version: 2.204.1
Git plugin: 4.0.0